# Meaning of a sentence in the book I'm reading :- How To Change Your Mind by Michael Pollan

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I came across a sentence in this book that I'm not able to wrap my mind around. Here, it is:

> Science has little interest in, and tolerance for, the testimony of the individual; in this it is, curiously, much like an organized religion, which has a big problem crediting direct revelation too.

The author is trying to draw a parallel between organized religion and science regarding what I assume is their intolerance for the testimony of the individual. But I don't understand what his point is.

Isn't the point of most religion to take individual testimonies to be the only truth and believe in them blindly? Maybe, the author is talking strictly from the Judeo-Christian perspective which I'm not pretty familiar with. Hence, not able to comprehend this.

Anyway, any insight into what anyone can understand from this will be a great help.

Comment: This question does not concern language at all; its answer is a matter of philosophy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not concern language at all; its answer is a matter of philosophy.

Comment: @LPH Fair point. I just wanted to know what the meaning is in this specific context? Is that outside of the scope of this forum. If yes then where should I pose this?. Sorry, but this my first time using stackexchange !

Comment: *According to the cited writer,* Science and Religion are similar in that they're both dismissive of "direct revelation". Which I'd say is a pretty daft claim to make anyway, regardless of whether he's  talking strictly from the Judeo-Christian perspective or not.

Comment: try https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LPH Thanks! I'll try there!

Comment: ("Science" has no relationship with "Direct revelation" to begin with, so it wouldn't even dignify it with a dismissive reaction. But many religions are essentially *based* on such concepts - Moses and the burning bush, in  Abrahamic religions, fior example.)

Comment: I believe they are so dismissive as far as grounds for tenets are to be accepted from mere testimony, not  when considering the possibility of new tenets; science for the least shows that to be strictly true.

Comment: I think what the writer is trying to say when he says "Religion has a big problem crediting direct revelation too.", is that Religions mostly never credit God as their progenitor for rules of moral conduct but rather Prophets and their divine intervention from God as their source for most of it. Or maybe that's a bit of a stretch

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [philosophy.SE]

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended parallel is that in both cases, any individual's assertions carry little weight with the establishment.

In the case of science, what matters is repeatability. If one person says something works, that isn't persuasive. But if many people independently say the same thing, it becomes more credible to the establishment.

The wording of the *religion* case is more convoluted.

English usage of "direct revelation" tends to imply that the revelation is genuine. However, the quote's usage isn't about "direct revelation" in this sense. It is referring to *claims* of direct revelation. It uses "crediting" in the following sense:

> **credit** *verb*
> 3 [British] Believe (something surprising or unlikely)
> ‘you would hardly credit it—but it was true’
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/credit)

The situation the quote alludes to is that of someone claiming direct revelation. It would be understandable for organised religion to require more proof than just that person's assertion. The parallel drawn is that science also requires more proof than just one individual's assertion.

Answer (score 0):

How to change your mind by Michael Pollan
"Science has little interest in, and tolerance for, the testimony of the individual; in this it is, curiously, much like an organized religion."

Your question is small about two large subjects.

On the contrary both Science and Religion are inherently about the individual experience. It is the organization of these very human activities that over time work to highlight the previous successes over the current experience. It has been the experience of humans to find that others have had much the same experience. The shock of this is part of growing up.

In reading more of Mr. Polland it seems he knows nothing substantive of science or organized religion except that he does not care for them. As such he finds they have *much* in common. This has helped him guard his his naive views on Mushrooms and LSD from much critical examination.

"Isn't the point of most religion to take individual testimonies to be the only truth and believe in them blindly."

As for believing in blindly that is a requirement for *political* belief where self deception is a means of survival.

Religion is the experience of *oneself* in the world along with a personal experience of God in the world. Working out how the two fit together is an individual struggle. The word Ligature is shared within *religion* and as such means tying or linking the individual together.

Organized religion is the ***tradition*** of gathering and retelling such *individual* experiences along with certain interpretations of those experiences. Human weakness tends to work overtime preserving traditions of all kinds, religious traditions being one of these. Like most human activities it may leave something to be desired. New religions often come from breaking away from the previous Organized religion when the tradition loses its flexibility in new circumstances.

Science is also based on the individual's experience. In this case it is their experience of first hand reality that is examined, not that of spirituality. Then the strict need to limit observation and consideration to only the facts of the problem at hand must be learned and practiced.

This itself becomes an organized human activity with all the inherent strengths and weaknesses. Reliability of a given phenomenon is the only currency of the realm. People originally wrote letters to one anther giving the details of procedures to see if the same results would be found. These became the scientific papers that are now published and meant to be reproduced. This practice has worked fantastically well until nowadays the phenomenon looked for are not boldly visible but hidden within much data.

An individual's scientific or religious experience after millennia of humanity will more than likely be similar to that of another. The function of experts in these *traditions* has been to tell you who may have had similar experiences and what was learned from it. All human activity is resistant to the new and it is overstating the case that science is particularly guilty of such offenses as Mr. Pollan does. Like most people growing up it has been the practice of Mr. Pollan to eschew such learned experience or his insights might not be considered entirely new and exciting.